# Greasemonkey- Picking random word(s) out of search engine results page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am working on a little project but I seem to be stuck at this point. Hopefully, some of you great people will be able to help me out on this.

I am trying to figure out a simple and efficient way of pick out a RANDOM word or words from a page of search engine results. This is the part I am stuck on.

After picking it out, I would store the word(s) in a variable.

The search results look like this: http://i54.tinypic.com/34fllw1.png

Thanks in advance. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Is there a way I would be able to pick out a string of consecutive words of random length?

Comment: And you only want the words to come from the visible page, nothing from the html code?

Comment: yes, preferably just from the descriptions in the results. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works with google.com

```
//get the text
var text=document.getElementById('rso').textContent;
  //find the words 
var words=text.match(/\b([a-z]{3,})\b/gi);
  //pick a word
alert(words[Math.floor(words.length*Math.random())]);
```

The searchresults are listed in an element with the ID "rso".
The regexp matches strings consisting of at least 3 chars a-z

Answer (score 1):

The class Google uses for descriptions is `st`, so here's an improvement of Dr.Molle's solutiom:

```
//get the text
var text=document.querySelector(".st"),output=[];
//loop through the descriptions
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    //find the words
    var words=text[i].innerText.match(/\b([a-z]{3,})\b/gi);
    //push the array to the output variable
    output.push.apply(output,words);
}
//pick a word
var theWord=output[Math.floor(Math.random()*output.length)];
//now theWord has a randomly chosen word
alert(theWord);
```

And to pick a few words out:

```
//change the 10 to the max number of words
var amount=Math.floor(Math.random()*10),theWords="";
    //get the text
var text=document.querySelector(".st"),output=[];
//loop through the descriptions
for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    //find the words
    var words=text[i].innerText.match(/\b([a-z]{3,})\b/gi);
    //push the array to the output variable
    output.push.apply(output,words);
}
//pick a word
var theNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*output.length);
//loops the code the number of times randomly chosen
for(var i=0;i<amount;i++){
    //add on to the string
    theWords+=(i==0?"":" ")+output[theNumber+i];
}
//now theWords has a random number of consecutive words
alert(theWords);
```

Ad@m

Comment: I see, this does narrow down the selection nicely to what I wanted. Thank you for the suggestion! I also wanted to ask, is there a way I would be able to pick out a string of consecutive words of random length?

Comment: Try replacing `[a-z]{3,}` with `[a-zA-Z ]{10,}` (with the space after A-Z). I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it will work. Ad@m

Comment: That works great! Another thing, is there a way I can exclude certain words from being selected? For example, the page has a lot of repeats of words such as "sponsor", that I don't want included in my selection. Thanks again!

Comment: Use the code I just put in my answer, and place this above the `thwWords+=` line: `if(output[theNumber+i].toLowerCase()=="sponsor"){continue;}`. Continue in JavaScript means to continue to the next iteration of the loop. Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete Greasemonkey script that grabs an arbitrary number of random words, just from the descriptions, and handles the variety of Google search pages a little better (They change the DOM slightly, depending on how the page was obtained.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _RandomWord from results
// @include         http://www.google.com/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function GrabRandomWords () {
    /*--- Google search results are wrapped in a list with the id "rso".
        Here, we want just the descriptions in the results, so we know
        that title and link tag tags can be excluded.
        (Alas, Google's search results pages vary quite a bit in the
        detailed structure of their HTML.)
    */
    var descriptText    = $("#rso li *:not(a,h1,h2,h3)").text ();

    //--- Split into words.  Change the "{1,}", if short words like "a" are to be excluded.
    var words           = descriptText.match (/\b(\w{1,})\b/g);

    //--- Pick 5 random words and store them in an array.
    if (words) {
        var ourRandWords    = [];
        for (var J = 0;  J < 5;  ++J)
            ourRandWords.push ( words[ Math.floor (words.length * Math.random() ) ] );

        alert (ourRandWords);
    }
}

//--- We must wait until page has fully loaded, because the results are usually Ajaxed in.
window.addEventListener ("load",
    function () {
        /*--- Page is "loaded", but results are still not in, still need a short delay.
            Note that listening for DOMSubtreeModified doesn't seem to work well.
        */
        setTimeout (function() { GrabRandomWords (); }, 666);
    },
    false
);
```

Comment: Wow~ this is very nice. Thank you for the additional ideas!